# Logging Prefetch value and Concurrent Message Limit value on startUp

Tags: c#, masstransit, servicebus

I'm using Azure Service Bus, MassTransit library and I would like to log Prefetch and Concurrent Message Limit values on the startup.

What are the options to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit doesn't log anything of that nature on startup, but you can [pull the configuration](https://masstransit-project.com/troubleshooting/show-config.html) and log it yourself.